# Feature list for question "Recommend me alternative to X"

Tags: discussion, question-quality, questions, alternatives

I have sample question for free alternative to paid software X.

I have upvoted comment, that I should list all features. Is this necessary? I'm looking for software that have similar features, and answerers should lists all differences or missing features. Answerer should know X and it feature list.

Are I'm correct with my expectations?

Sample question: [Free equivalent for Splunk log manager](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16/free-equivalent-for-splunk-log-manager)

Comment: Consider the situation where answerer does not know X but a different tool that suits the same needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to phrase this in terms of a replacement. Just describe the features you like in Splunk, a brief description of what it does, and then add that you want something that isn't proprietary in your constraints.

You can *add* that Splunk won't work for you because it's proprietary, but you want the same set of features.

Just describe your need, not so much what you're trying to replace.