# Is my question bad or off topic?

Tags: support, question-quality, specific-question

[This](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4313/need-an-extension-to-view-the-office-documents-in-chrome) is my first question in Software Recommendation. I am surprised to see so many downvotes. Is the question really that bad? Please someone explain so I can delete my question after knowing the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glad you brought this topic to Meta, sameer – that's the best place to seek clarification of this kind!

Downvoters should have commented and give you hints *why* they downvoted. But unfortunately, they don't always do that. I was not one of them, so I can only guess. But taking a look at your question, a good guess is it's lacking required information (which it definitely does). It might help you to take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) to see what makes a "good question". Summed up:

- a user story (what's the background, what do you want to achieve)
- a list of specific requirements (what are must-haves, what are (optional) nice-to-haves)
- don't forget to specify the intended platform (which OS, if applicable, or whether it should be a web-app)

Another indicator is already given by Nick's comment: Before posting your question, make sure it's on-topic. Some *general* pointers (not all related to your specific question, that is):

- **off-topic:**

  - looking for a hosting/service provider: [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)
  - troubleshooting a piece of software
  - asking to compare "product X versus product Y"
  - what is *the best* X (opinion based; frowned on on all SE sites. Of course we don't recommend "the worst". If I *recommend* anything, I do so for a *good* reason :)
  - can you please *list some* alternatives to... (list-type answers are frowned upon as well on the entire SE) We don't want bullet-list-of-names, but specific, high-quality answers here.
  - "I need a software like X" (without any details on what X is). Rather specify your requirements (not just link to the "other" product: all criteria should be contained *in your post*, as a) the link might rot/die, and b) you cannot expect potential answerers to "jump around" to collect *your* requirements ;) Not everybody knows X, but might know a good "similar" product. See:

    - [Feature list for question “Recommend me alternative to X”](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/101/185)
    - [Is it okay to ask for alternatives?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/185)
    - [How to ask for an alternative to some software](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185)
  - I want to learn about X. Any good books/tutorials? → This is *Software* Recommendations, not "general recommendations" :) See: [Questions that do not ask for recommended software on topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/703/185)
- **on-topic:**

  - which software do you recommend to {do X}, ***and meets the following criteria:*** …

---

### Further recommended readings:

- [What if we don't know exactly what we want?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/745/185)
- [How to ask for advice on a very specific topic which I don't know in deep?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/799/185?lq=1)
- [Is it OK to ask for a software having a particular feature?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/691/185?lq=1)
- [Criteria you should mention in your question, for each type of software](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/844/185?lq=1)
- [How to ask and answer software recommendation questions - aka 'The Ground Rules'](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/455/185?rq=1)
- [Are “What are criteria for X” on-topic](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/98/185)
- [What happens when someone needs one very specific feature?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/710/185)